Generate a random set of numbers with 2 different sum conditions in Excel or Python
I am generating 202 sets of 4 numbers. The sum of each set of 4 needs to be 30, but I only want it to generate numbers such that the first number of each set of 4 sums to 500, the second number of each set sums to 500, the third number in each set sums to 300, and the fourth number sums to 200.
In Excel, I am using =INT(RAND()100) to generate a random integer 1-100, then applying =A130/SUM(A1:A4) to make sure the sum of each set of 4 sums to 30. I then tried =B7*20/SUM(B1,B5,B9) testing to see if I could get the first values of the first 3 sets to sum to a value (20) and that works as well. So, I found a way to generate numbers whose sums is 30, and a way to generate so every first number sums to a value, but not both. I cannot figure out a way to combine the conditions though so that both summations work.

This could be an interesting question but it's really hard to follow without a picture or (better) a table in markdown format that we can copy. We don't know what's in A130 or B7, for instance. Plz see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Hey, 202 sets of 4 = 30 per row, matching to the sums for columns (500 + 500 + 300 + 200), is that correct?

What you are asking is impossible.
Let's analyze the problem mathematically.
The given constraints suggest that we have n sets of numbers a_i + b_i + c_i + d_i. The following equations summarize the constraints:
a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n = 500
b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_n = 500
c_1 + c_2 + ... + c_n = 300
d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_n = 200

Then if we put everything together and reorganize a little:
  (a_1 + a_2 + ... + a_n) 
+ (b_1 + b_2 + ... + b_n) 
+ (c_1 + c_2 + ... + c_n)
+ (d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_n) = 1500

Reorganizing:
  (a_1 + b_1 + c_1 + d_1) 
+ (a_2 + b_2 + c_2 + d_2) 
+ ...
+ (a_n + b_n + c_n + d_n) = 1500

Additionally, every set must satisfy the constraint a_i + b_i + c_i + d_i = 30:
From the previous equation (n times):

30 + 30 + ... + 30 = 1500
30 n = 1500
   n = 50

Therefore, the maximum number of sets that can be generated is 50.

RIght.  202 sets of 30 sum to 6,060, but 500+500+300+200 is 1,500.
